# Call method and handle excption using java 8 foreach loop

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am executing below code if condition is satisfied I am generating exception ,but even if I will get exception I want to skip that loop and want to executive remain code so is there any way?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("1");
        items.add("2");
        items.add("3");
        items.add("4");
        items.add("5");

        try {
            items.forEach(item -> getData(item));
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void getData(String item) {
        System.out.println("====getData method called" + item + "====");
        if (item.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println(1 / 0);
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Unclear. Do you want to execute the line `System.out.println("execute remaining code");` even if the 3 lines of code before that line throw an exception? If so, catch the exception. If you would like to execute the remaining iterations og the loop even if `getData(item)` throws an exception, then once again: wrap the call to getData() inside a try block, and catch the exception.

Comment: If you catch the exception outside your loop, you have exited the loop. If you catch the exception _inside_ the loop (e.g. inside `getData`), you can continue the loop.

Comment: I just want to ignore exception and excute loop for remaing code

Comment: @Tejal check the answer. it should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `try`/`catch` inside the loop?

```
    items.forEach(item -> {
        try {
            getData(item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put try catch inside `getData` method at the block of code where exception may occur so in this case it will continue loop for others items if any exception occured:

```
public static void getData(String item) {
        try {
             System.out.println("====getData method called" + item + "====");
             if (item.equals("1")) {
                 System.out.println(1 / 0);
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception at item: " + item);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
 }
```